# App Inventor Fusion Table Column calling

Tags: google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I developed an app based on App Inventor and Fusion Tables. When I want to update total money by adding some money to already existing money it is giving some  error.

When I use SELECT command to get information from fusion table it is taking then number with column Name. When i am trying to add both of them it is giving following error.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGbgl.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The result from a fusiontable includes always the header row...
from your example SELECT statement the result is

```
TotalPaid
5000
```

Obviously to add any value to that result will result in an error, because you only can add numeric values...

You first have to extract the value (in your example 5000) from the result. Convert the result into a list using the `split` block, just split at **\n** (new value) to get a list, then select the 2nd item using the `select list item` block.

Note: to be able to update something in a table, you need the ROWID, see also the [SQL Reference Documentation of the Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#updateRow).

For UPDATE statements the first step to be done is to get the ROWID of the row to be updated with a SELECT statement. The second step is to do the UPDATE.